# Why cant i use the autosave variable in the Following code?

Tags: python, string, boolean

The function works by looking at the string-value of the autosave and setting it to "yes" or "no". The programm itself seems that it wont reference to the variable.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from isbnlib import meta, canonical, is_isbn10, is_isbn13

fenster = Tk()
fenster.geometry("500x500")
fenster.title("Meine Bibliothek")
books = []
titel = ""
file = ""
autosave = ""
while file == None or file == "":
    file = askstring("Liste", "Wie heist deine Buchliste?")
autosave = messagebox.askquestion("autosave", "Soll autosave aktiviert werden?")
print(autosave)

def changeBookName():
    print()

def autosave_Books():
    if autosave.__eq__("yes"):
        autosave = "no"
        messagebox.showinfo("Autosave", "Autosave ist jetzt aus")
    else:
        autosave = "yes"
        messagebox.showinfo("Autosave", "Autosave ist jetzt an")
    
def addBook():
    text = ISBN_Box.get()
    if not text.__eq__(""):
        try:
            meta_dict = meta(text,service='goob')
            titel = meta_dict['Title']
            print(titel)
            titel = titel.split(" - ")[0]
            print(titel)
            Book_Label.config(text="Book:    "+titel)
            answer = messagebox.askyesno(message="Name ändern?")
            print(answer)
            if answer:
                newName = askstring("Name", "Neuer Name:")
                print(newName)
                if not newName == None:
                    titel = newName
                    Book_Label.config(text="Book:    "+titel)
            wholebook = titel + " (" + text + ")"
            print(wholebook)
            if autosave.__eq__("yes"):
                s = open(file, "w")
                for items in books:
                    s.write(items + "\n")
            else:
                books.append(wholebook)
            show_Books()
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Buch hinzugefügt")
        except:
            messagebox.showerror(message="Keine gültige ISBN",title="Error")

def del_Books():
    shortsave = []
    delete = []
    dr = open(file, "r")
    titel = askstring("Löschen", "Welches Buch möchtest du löschen? (Nenne ISBN oder Titel)")
    if not titel == None:
        for items in dr:
            if not items.__contains__(titel):
                shortsave.append(items)
            else:
                delete.append(items)
        dr.close()
        if delete.count == 0:
            dw = open(file, "w")
            for items in shortsave:
                dw.write(items)
            messagebox.showinfo(message="Bücher gelöscht")
            show_Books()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(message="Kein Buch zu gegebenen Daten gefunden")
    delete.clear()
    shortsave.clear()
    

def save_Books():
    s = open(file, "w")
    for items in books:
        s.write(items + "\n")
    messagebox.showinfo(message="Bücher gespeichert")
        

def show_Books():
    showbooks = []
    for items in books:
        showbooks.append(items+"\n")
    Book_List.config(text=showbooks)

#Menüleiste inizialisieren
menuleiste = Menu(fenster)
Datei_menu = Menu(menuleiste,tearoff=0)
Datei_menu.add_command(label="Save",command=save_Books)
Datei_menu.add_separator()
Datei_menu.add_command(label="Löschen", command=del_Books)
Datei_menu.add_separator()
Datei_menu.add_command(label="Exit",command=fenster.quit)
Datei_menu.add_separator()
Datei_menu.add_command(label="Autosave",command=autosave_Books)

#Menüleiste  hinzufügen
menuleiste.add_cascade(label="Datei",menu=Datei_menu)
fenster.config(menu=menuleiste)

#Komponenten inizialisieren
ISBN_Label = Label(fenster, text="ISBN:")
ISBN_Box = Entry(fenster, bd=5, width=40)
ISBNadd_Button = Button(fenster,text="Buch hinzufügen", command=addBook)
Book_Label = Label(fenster,text="Buch:")
Book_List = Label(fenster, text="Bücher werden hier angezeigt")

#Komponenten auf Fenster legen
ISBN_Label.grid(row=0,column=0)
ISBN_Box.grid(row=0,column=1)
ISBNadd_Button.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
Book_Label.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
Book_List.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2)
fenster.mainloop()
```

The problems are popping up when i try to execute the autosave_Books() function

I tried it with boolean, string and also refering to other bools by maching the values. Nothing works :/

Comment: Why are you using `.__eq__` instead of `==` in many places?

Comment: Its clearer for me. I just like it more

Comment: I think I understand why you have "crazy" in your user name now.

Comment: You need `global autosave` in the functions that assign the variable.